# How to manage number of left items in an ecommerce website for items with limited quantity?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, e-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce site in node, We have an item with limited quantity, so as soon as the user selects I made it so that number of items he asked for is checked and if okay those items will be decremented from database, but then if the user does not complete the payment, it will be a mess. So if you guys could advice a better strategy it'll be cool example project or code will be even more cooler!

Answer (score 0):

Cache the description along with the price of the product, so when each request comes for the item it will return the Product description and price if quantity is more than one. On every purchase(payment in your case) of the product, reduce the quantity of particular item in the database. When product stock reaches to zero, remove it from the cache or show it to customer as out of show. It's normal way ecommerce works.

Comment: I don't get it. cache meaning? like users cart?

Comment: place these data on RAM using the redis / memcache.